# Why is Windows 8 Not Using the Correct Interface to Route Packets

Tags: windows, windows-8, routing, cisco-vpn-client

Yesterday afternoon, I was suddenly unable to route packets to my company's vpn on my Windows 8 machine even though I am "successfully" connected.  Can anyone explain to me how, with this routing table, windows is attempting to use the 192.168.2.1 interface instead of the 172.30.0.1 for 172.29.3.91?  I've compared this table to my win 7 machine that works fine and I can't see any difference.  What the heck is going on here?

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert -d 172.29.3.91

Tracing route to 172.29.3.91 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.2.1
  2  ^C
C:\Windows\system32>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 12...bc 5f f4 44 9c 00 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
 31...00 05 9a 3c 78 00 ......Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 20...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 22...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1      192.168.2.4     50
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
       ***172.16.0.0      255.240.0.0       172.30.0.1    172.30.128.96    100***
       172.30.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link     172.30.128.96    266
    172.30.128.96  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.30.128.96    266
   172.30.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.30.128.96    266
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0       172.30.0.1    172.30.128.96    100
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.2.4    306
      192.168.2.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.4    100
      192.168.2.4  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.4    306
    192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.4    306
     206.XXX.XXX.XXX    255.255.255.0       172.30.0.1    172.30.128.96    100
   208.XXS.XXX.XXX  255.255.255.255      192.168.2.1      192.168.2.4    100
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.2.4    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     172.30.128.96    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.4    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.30.128.96    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

C:\Windows\system32>tracert -d 172.30.0.1

Tracing route to 172.30.0.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

1     4 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.2.1
  2     *        *     ^C

Answer (score 0):

I'm no routing guru, but I had a similar (but diff) problem with Win8 with Ethernet and WiFi connected to two different networks, and WiFi set as the preferential network in the Advanced network settings. Works fine in Win7, but Win8 kept using Ethernet only.

I solved my problem by manually assigning metrics to the interfaces I wanted to prefer.

What would happen if you reduced the metric of that 172 route to below 50? But then would it try to send everything over the VPN rather than using the default gateway? Sorry, not a TCP guru.